# Открытие модального окна

Tags: html, bootstrap

Собственно проблема, при открытии модального окна (от bootstrap)  на странице скролл страницы переводится в самый верх. Как можно от этого избавиться?

модальное окно

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalView" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content" style="background: linear-gradient(#1A1E21, #1A1E21, #1A1E21);; color: #fff;">
            <div class="modal-header"">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalViewTitle"></h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >
                    <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff !important;">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
                <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                    <img src="" alt="photo" width="90%" height="auto" id="modalViewImage">
                    <p id="modalViewText" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 20px;">

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

влияет это или нет, но это тоже выложу

```
<html lang="en" style='overflow-x: hidden;'>
```

модальное окно открывается через js

```
$(".view").click(function() {
    $("#modalView").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: код покажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @artem55555p не знаю, что вы тут можете увидеть, но пожалуйста, вставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Когда модальное окно открывается, класс `modal-open` устанавливает тег `<body>`. Этому классу присваивается `overflow: hidden;` к тегу `body`. Добавьте это в css, чтобы переопределить стиль bootstrap.css:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

**Вариант 2**

Смотря как вы вызываете открытие окна. Если через тег `<a href="#myModal">`, то оно будет скролиться, попробуйте сделать так:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Кнопка
</button>
```

**Вариант 3**

```
$('ваш класс').click(function ($e) {
    $e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: помогло, но теперь при открытии модального окна у всей страницы справа появляется небольшой отступ

Comment: @epsilon скрин можно?

Comment: если честно, я не знаю, как сюда картинки вставлять. но я забыл сказать, что открываю модальное окно через js

 `$(".view").click(function() {
 $("#modalView").modal('show');
}`

пытался сделать как в 3 варианте, не помогло

Comment: @epsilon может это полоса скролла появляется?

Comment: посмотрел исходный код, при открытии модального окна к body добавляется padding-right: 17px

Comment: @epsilon уберите его и все))

Comment: да, я знаю) просто хотел вас проинформировать. спасибо за помощь)